# filling up a table empty rows with a border css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a designated area for a table, and sometimes the table doesn't get filled up completely to the bottom of that area after reading from database. For the empty spaces I want to have a border around it connecting to the table, so it looks like the table is all the way to the bottom but the remaining space will just be a big empty space enclosed by a border (looks like it's part of the table)

Any tips on how to do that? prefer to use only css

code:

```
    <div class="col-md-11" style="width:86%">
        <div class="table-responsive user-table" style="overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table_{{table.name}}">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="header in table.headers track by $index" style="background-color: #0D3C47; color:white">
                            <div data-ng-if="header.type !== 'checkbox'">{{header}}</div>
                            <div data-ng-if="header.type === 'checkbox'">{{header.value}}</div>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in table.rows track by $index">
                        @*<tr ng-repeat="row in table.rows | activeOrNot: table.checkboxCol: table.filterIsEnabled track by $index">*@

                        <td ng-repeat="item in row | filter: {type: '!GUID'} track by $index "
                            ng-click="table.selectedRow(row)"
                            ng-class="{ 'highlight' : row === table.selected}">

                            <div data-ng-if="item.type === undefined">{{item}}</div>
                            <div data-ng-if="item.type === 'checkbox'">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.checked" ng-disabled="true">
                            </div>
                            <div data-ng-if="item.type === 'GUID'">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-right" style="padding-right: 30px; font-size: 15px">
                        <div>Showing result {{table.entries.displayingAmount}} of {{table.entries.totalAmount}}</div>
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

    </div>
```

This is bootstrap. The only css styling for this is the class `user-table` has a `height: 720`

A pic of what the codes does, and what I want it to look like:
https://awwapp.com/s/c7447569-50a4-49a7-805b-43eb0770985f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some different class and Div as a new container

Here is your complete code : http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/PzAPEW

To clarify:

You class must have border right and left

```
.user-table{
  height: 720px; 
  border-right:1px solid #ddd;
  border-left:1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0px;
  border-top:0px;
  border-bottom:0px;
}
```

and also you need to add a new class to first table to remove extra borders for example I named my class no-bottom

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered no-bottom" id="table_{{table.name}}">
```

try to remove border in css 
feel free to modify as much as you want

```
.table-bordered.no-bottom{
  margin-bottom:0px;
  border-right:0px;
  border-left:0px;
}
```

and then now you may also need to change border in classes below:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th{ }
```

remember you should add your custom class to the classed above to avoid global change.

that's it. you have what you want. you can see result here http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/PzAPEW